# Exposing port 8083 for kafka on docker gives error

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect

the image of the docker-compose file is given below.

```
version: '2'
 
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:3'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    volumes:
      - 'zookeeper_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes

  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:2'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '29092:29092'
      - '8083:8083'
    volumes:
      - 'kafka_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:29092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper    
volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local
```

The image works prefect when I dont try to expose the port 8083 on kafka. When I try to expose the port it throws error and the container stops. My major problem is I need to acess kafka connect but Iam not able to do it inside the docker container with this configuration. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be your local machine does not have an 8083 port free!
Look for it and try to change that port bindings

```
- '8084:8083'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have something running elsewhere occupying that port

Kafka broker doesn't run anything on 8083 and your exposed listeners to the host  is only 29092

If you're trying to run Kafka Connect, use another container, not the broker

> Iam not able to do it inside the docker container with this configuration

Use kafka:9092